# Rotational transition of a vibrational band of a CO$_2$ molecule?

Tags: laser, molecules, raman-spectroscopy

I am currently reading this paper in regards to the lasing transitions of the CO$_2$ molecule:

https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.136.A1187

Specifically, it keeps mentioning the rotational transitions of the vibrational band of CO$_2$, and I am unsure how how to visualize this for a CO$_2$ molecule. Can anyone help here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational%E2%80%93vibrational_spectroscopy